# What is the term for all of the RNA in a cell at any given time?

Tags: genetics, cell-biology, rna

Question is asked above, simply put.

Comment: Transcriptome..

Comment: @WYSIWYG, I think that is more like the RNA profile, as opposed to total RNA?

Comment: @AliceD It means all RNA. When you want to imply profile you usually say transcriptome profile or transcriptome profiling (the process of finding the profile). For miRNAs they say miRnome profiling. Also terms like dynamic transcriptome etc have been used.

Comment: You have to clarify your question: in what context do you want to use the term? Total RNA as a term is used generally in the sense of RNA isolation but not in the sense of cellular processes i.e. you won't say we studied the effect of stress on total RNA. Total RNA is used when you mean all RNA lumped as a whole and transcriptome is used in the sense of collection of all RNAs.

Comment: @WYSIWYG it's not just the transcriptome (mRNA), as there are also transfer RNAs, micro RNAs, ribosomal RNAs, etc.

Comment: @MattDMo Transcriptome includes all RNAs, not just mRNAs (anything that is transcribed). People usually are not interested in rRNAs in their analyses; so they exclude them. That's why probably most readers may have an impression that transcriptome means just mRNAs.

Comment: @WYSIWYG [you're right](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transcriptome). My bad :) When I think of transcription, for some reason I only think about protein-coding genes, which are transcribed and processed into mRNA. I'm more protein- and cell-focused than gene-focused, which probably explains why. I forgot that *every* RNA is coded in the genome. TIL.

Comment: I'd agree with WYSIWYG. The two are usually used in a different sense. Total RNA is typically used when referring to the sum total mass, as in RNA isolation, but not the composition (on the level of specific RNA expression patterns). Transcriptome is typically used when referring to the relative expression of each individual RNA transcript within a cell.

Answer (score 4):

[Qiagen](https://www.qiagen.com/us/resources/faq?id=06a192c2-e72d-42e8-9b40-3171e1eb4cb8&lang=en) and [Life Technologies](https://www.lifetechnologies.com/au/en/home/references/ambion-tech-support/rna-isolation/general-articles/rna-yields-from-tissues-and-cells.html) call it  ***RNA content***, ***total RNA***, or ***total cellular RNA***.

Comment: i hear 'total RNA' often